# Where can I buy music?

Tags: music

With UbuntuOne closing down, Emusic quitting al suppport for their linuxclient, I have but one question:

Where can I spent my Euros to buy legal music. On Ubuntu?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I download/buy music?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/201460/how-do-i-download-buy-music)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [7digital](http://www.7digital.com/). Ubuntu One was using 7digital as music provider, but with different agreements for territorial limitations. If 7digital is available for your country, you may even find many more musics available for purchase.

7digital for Nederlands : http://nl.7digital.com/

Comment: I've yet to try 7-digital. Do you have any hands-on experience? Does it work out of the box and deliver my buys to my harddrive or musicplayer?

Comment: Yes, it works out of the box. No need to install anything on your system. You just have to download the songs you buy one by one (mp3 files) OR one ZIP archive per album OR one ZIP archive with what you've just purchased. The songs are generally well tagged and have embedded covers which is perfect with Rhythmbox, Banshee or else.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Spotify](http://www.spotify.com), you can install it from its website at this [page](https://www.spotify.com/fr/download/linux/). It has two plan types: free, that doesn't allow to download music, and has a lot of ads, and premium, that hasn't any ad, and allows you to download music on your computer, not as MP3, but in a special format, recognized only by Spotify Player.

Comment: Spotify has two bit problems IMHO. When my wife plays music at her place, my music stops; we cannot share our accounts. And I don't "own" the music. With e-music, being DRM-free, I own all the ogg/mp3s I bought the last few years.

Comment: @berkes There is now a linux preview, which, while buggy, is quite good, and integrates into the sound menu. And to get around the playlist problem, have 2 accounts, and send each other the playlist?

Answer (score 0):

it's simple with Google as you know or not they launched Google Music service not so long ago and there's extension also available for Google Chrome and Chromium browsers alike, where you can listen and buy music of your taste.

[Google Play Music Shop](https://play.google.com/store/music?feature=music_general)

Comment: How does it work on Ubuntu? Does it "Just Work [tm]"? When I pay for stuff, I prefer it to work with less hassle than pirating it.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean exactly? it's simple but yet official and legal service from Google where you can listen and buy music, it synchronizes with your google account. More detailed info and its policy you can read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Play_Music)

Comment: I use google music on an Ubuntu derivative, and it plays great.

Answer (score 0):

The Amazon MP3 store is available in [some countries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_MP3#Catalog_availability):

> United States, United Kingdom, Germany, France, Austria, Switzerland, Japan, Italy, Spain

They let you both stream the songs and download the MP3 files using a web browser. If you want to download multiple files at one time you have to install their client, though.